# Multiple Build Definitions in VSTS with only one checkout folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can i use multiple build definitions (triggered by path) with only one repository and without duplicate checkouts on the Build Agent?

So basically:

- One Repo
- Checkout once(!)
- Build all definitions depending on path trigger

Currently, every build definition is checked out separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "checkout" you actually mean "cloned" (in Git terms) or "workspace synchronized" (in TFVC terms).

If that's the case, then you can't do that. Each build is isolated on an agent-by-agent and definition-by-definition basis. This allows the same build to run concurrently across multiple agents with no chances of collisions or race conditions occurring.

If the reason you want to do this is because your repository is very large, then chances are you can alleviate this by using tighter workspace mappings (in TFVC) or multiple repositories connected together via submodules, or even sparse checkouts (in Git).

Comment: My repository is very large, yes. I will take a look at sparse checkouts and workspace mappings, thanks.